# Would asking about Pantone color types and difference would be off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

When you search any code using [this](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder#/search), it shows 2 types of results. I don't understand them. Can I ask this question on GD SE?

Comment: Have you searched the questions for the code? I'm pretty sure we have a couple of questions about these but your link only shows a search form for me

Comment: You could, but there are already some questions about this. Have a look at [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/125295/84899) answer.